# Flutter 2.8.0 not running apps on MacOS but run on Android (on Mac M1)

Tags: firebase, macos, flutter, crashlytics, apple-m1

After upgrading to Flutter 2.8.0, I can't run my app on MacOS, receiving this error :

```
/Users/cac/Programming/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-2.4.3/macos/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.m:6:9: fatal error: 'Crashlytics_Platform.h' file not found
#import "Crashlytics_Platform.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Maybe it's an issue, but I need a turn around for now:
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/discussions/7484